# JavaScript: How to terminate Asterisk when excel data start at Asterisk

Tags: javascript, excel, if-statement

I am trying to read excel data using if statement where when Script find any Data starting with Asterisk then script read that data from excel sheet by terminating that Asterisk from that alpha numeric data and populate that data in the field on web application.

For example Following is my excel sheet format:

```
Data Description  Actual Data

    First Name         John
    Last Name          Smith
    Date Of Birth      *02/25/1960
```

You can notice that I mentioned Asterisk just before the date of birth that I want JavaScript read only when script identify that there is Asterisk mentioned just before the Date of Birth. Otherwise just ignore date of birth.

Following code I used:

```
var $dueDate = person.$dueDate;

if ($dueDate == ("*") != -1)

{       

     $dueDate = $dueDate.replace(/\*/g,'');

    var $dueDate = person.$dueDate;

    person.$dueDate = $dueDate;

    _log('Due Date is:' + $dueDate);

}
```

Comment: consider posting your read function...

Comment: here is the function:    if ($dueDate == ("*") != -1) { var $dueDate = person.$dueDate; person.$dueDate = $dueDate; _log('Due Date is:' + $dueDate);

Comment: Take care to correctly spell JavaScript to avoid search collision with Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to check the appearance of * into your string, consider the following simple example,

```js
   

 $(function(){
    var strDate = ["*2/11/1983","3/4/1867","4/11/1990"];
    $.each(strDate,function(i){
      if(strDate[i].indexOf("*") != -1){
strDate[i] = strDate[i].replace(/\*/g,'') // Include this if you need to remove * from string
        console.log(strDate[i]);
      }
    })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: hi user7417866 - I updated my function using your answer as below:          if ($dueDate == ("*") != -1)

 {  
  var $dueDate = person.$dueDate;

  person.$dueDate = $dueDate;

  _log('Due Date is:' + $dueDate);

Comment: how can I terminate Asterisk after reading that date ? because web field doesn't accept Asterisk along with date.

Comment: wht's this ` if ($dueDate == ("*") != -1) ` is it working for you? secondly do you want to remove * from date?

Comment: yes since this is reading from excel so it is working with this code ` if ($dueDate == ("*") != -1) `     And let me update code in order to terminate Asterisk.

Comment: I updated code in order to terminate Asterisk but it is not terminating Asterisk.

Comment: I edited code as below and finally code is terminating Asterisk as below:          var $dueDate = person.$dueDate;

 if ($dueDate == ("*") != -1)
     
 {  
   
  var $dueDate = person.$dueDate;
  
   $dueDate = person.$dueDate.replace(/\*/g,'');

  person.$dueDate = $dueDate;

  _log('Due Date is:' + $dueDate);

 }